# Cant find the length of my array in react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, pagination, react-bootstrap

So I'm trying to create pagination for my react-bootstrap application. I want to access the total length of my array so I can divide it with `ItemPerPage` to show the related pagination number button.

**For example** if the array length is `10` and `ItemperPage` is `2` so there will be `5` pagination button from `1` to `5`.

But the problem is I can't access the array length.

I tried to use `object.Keys().length` to get the number of length but because at the beginning of the **API fetch** *my array is **undefined*** it shows some error `"Cannot convert undefined or null to object"`.

How can I do error handling for the array ? so that when first fetching the API data which is undefined it won't show error and later on when the data is fetched it can show the correct data. I tried using ternary, but the problem is not solved.

here's my code:

```
<Paginations
  itemPerPage= {itemPerPage}
  totalItems= {Object.keys(productList).length}
  paginate={paginate}
/>
```

my pagination code:

```
function Paginations({itemPerPage, totalItems, paginate}) {
    const pageNumbers =[];
    for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(totalItems/ itemPerPage); i++ ){
      pageNumbers.push(
        <Pagination.Item key={i}>
          {i}
        </Pagination.Item>
      );
    }

  return (
    <div className="text-center">
        <Pagination onClick={( )=> paginate()}>{pageNumbers}</Pagination>
    </div>
  )
}
```

my Object array example:

```
"count": 11,
"next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/products/?page=2",
"previous": null,
"results": [
        {
            "id": 7,
            "slug": "fleco-dual-usb-car-charger-cc-01",
            "sku": "FDSB01CC",
            "name": "Fleco Dual USB Car Charger CC-01",
            "description": "Fleco Dual USB Car Charger CC-01 merupakan sebuah barang yang berguna dalam mobil untuk charger",
            "weight": 20,
            "price": 50000,
            "stock": 20,
            "datetime_added": "2022-03-19T08:38:14.997244Z",
            "images": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/products/Fleco_Dual_USB_Car_Charger_CC-01.jpg"
                }
            ],
            "brand": {
                "id": 6,
                "slug": "fleco",
                "name": "Fleco",
                "image": null
            },
            "category": {
                "id": 6,
                "slug": "charger",
                "name": "Charger",
                "image": null
            }
        },
```

Comment: why `Object.keys(productList || {}).length` is not working? also you can use the productList as a spinner/loading condition like `!productList ? <Loading/> : <Paginations />`

Comment: I tried to do it using ternary like code below:

        { productList === undefined ?(
            <h1>loading</h1>
          ) : (
            <Paginations
              itemPerPage= {itemPerPage}
              totalItems= {totalItem}
              paginate={paginate}
            />
          )
        }

but when the productList value change form undefined into the contained the array, it's not showing the paginationb ox

Comment: It's another problem. You have to fix Paginations component. Add useEffect hook and make all pageNumbers inside it. Make pageNumbers as a state (useState hook).

Comment: can you help me with some code example please ?

Comment: Can't you just pass the length of `productList` with a fallback to zero is it is undefined? `totalItems= {productList?.length ?? 0}`. In `Paginations` set an early return `if (totalItems === 0) return null`

Answer (score 0):

With `!productlist` you check only if productlist is `not empty or null`. This should help without having to use async functionality .

```
<Paginations
  itemPerPage= {itemPerPage}
  totalItems= {Object.keys(!productList).length}
  paginate={paginate}
/>
```

Comment: it didn't work, i tried to console lout the total Items and the length is set to 0 when it should contain some value in this case it's 4

Comment: Can you check if your Paginations component is rerendered when you get the count from your API?

Answer (score 0):

Try this implementation
1 add productList || {} condition (productList can be undefined)
2 add useEffect hook for calculations (you can improve it by adding 0 conditions and etc)
3 use state hoke (useState) to save pageNumbers calculation result

```
{productList ? <Paginations
  itemPerPage= {itemPerPage}
  totalItems= {Object.keys(productList || {}).length}
  paginate={paginate}
/> : <Loading />}

function Paginations({itemPerPage, totalItems, paginate}) {
    const [itemsCount, setItemsCount] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        const pageNumbers =[];
        for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(totalItems/ itemPerPage); i++ ){
          pageNumbers.push(
             <Pagination.Item key={i}>
                  {i}
              </Pagination.Item>
          );
       }

       setItemsCount(pageNumbers)
    }, [totalItems])

  return (
    <div className="text-center">
        <Pagination onClick={( )=> paginate()}>{pageNumbers} </Pagination>
    </div>
  )
}
```